# Why the parameter of `h` will judge whether it is null twice in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer?

Tags: java, concurrency

Recently i am learning about concurrency.When i learn more about `Semaphore`,i have some questions.

This is the code of `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` in JDK1.8 (line 727):

```
private void setHeadAndPropagate(Node node, int propagate) {
        Node h = head; // Record old head for check below
        setHead(node);
       
        if (propagate > 0 || h == null || h.waitStatus < 0 ||
            (h = head) == null || h.waitStatus < 0) {
            Node s = node.next;
            if (s == null || s.isShared())
                doReleaseShared();
        }
    }
```

Why do it judge `h` whether it is null twice here? When `h` can will be null? I think neither of them can be null.

Comment: Do you have link to the source of code?

Comment: @user7294900[AbstractQueuedSynchronizer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java?view=markup) and [Semaphore](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.java?view=markup)

Comment: FWIW: This is the [changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/99b7bbe0474f) when the last two checks were added. The change in the comments might give us a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacause the head node is dynamic move ,
invoke `doReleaseShared()` come from two sides:

1.held the lock's Thread invoke `release()`then execute `doReleaseShared()`.

2.someone Thread execute `acquire()` ,preNode is head and acquire lock success the lock and then execute `doReleaseShared()`;

Considering the following possible order of execution:

here is some node :
head--->init node--->node1--->node2

someone release lock and then  wake up the node1,the node1 resumed from unpark,(node1's Thread named Thread1,node2's Thread named Thread2...)
node1's preNode is head,and acquire success,permit is one at the point.

```
private void doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int arg)
        throws InterruptedException {
        final Node node = addWaiter(Node.SHARED);
        boolean failed = true;
        try {
            for (;;) {
                final Node p = node.predecessor();
                if (p == head) {
                    int r = tryAcquireShared(arg);//success , r=0;
                    if (r >= 0) { //true
                        setHeadAndPropagate(node, r);
                        p.next = null; // help GC
                        failed = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                    parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                    throw new InterruptedException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (failed)
                cancelAcquire(node);
        }
    }
```

while the Thread1 is temporarily suspended after execute `setHead(node)`.

```
private void setHeadAndPropagate(Node node, int propagate) {
        Node h = head; // Thread2 come here and the Thread1 execute continue
        setHead(node);

        //Note: this point,the setHead(node) is done,but time slice 
        //      exhaustion,Thread1 is temporarily suspended 
                     
       
        if (propagate > 0 || h == null || h.waitStatus < 0 ||
            (h = head) == null || h.waitStatus < 0) {
            Node s = node.next;
            if (s == null || s.isShared())
                doReleaseShared();
        }
    }
```

another Thread release lock.current head is node1,CAS set node1's waitStatus==0,and wake up node2 .

node2 preHead is node1 and acquire lock success.then execute `setHeadAndPropagate()` method .

It happened that `Node node = head`,and the Thread2 continue...

```
if (propagate > 0 || h == null || h.waitStatus < 0 ||
            (h = head) == null || h.waitStatus < 0) {
            Node s = node.next;
            if (s == null || s.isShared())
                doReleaseShared();
        }
//return immediate ,because 
//to old head
//propagate=0 false
//h==null fase
//h.waitStatus=0 false
//to new head node1
//propagate=0 false
//h==null fase
//h.waitStatus=0 false
```

so let's back

```
 private void doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int arg)
        throws InterruptedException {
        final Node node = addWaiter(Node.SHARED);
        boolean failed = true;
        try {
            for (;;) {
                final Node p = node.predecessor();
                if (p == head) {
                    int r = tryAcquireShared(arg);
                    if (r >= 0) {
                        setHeadAndPropagate(node, r);
                        p.next = null; // help GC //node1 could be GC!!!
                        failed = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                    parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                    throw new InterruptedException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (failed)
                cancelAcquire(node);
        }
    }
```

finally,we back to Thread2,Thread2 continue.

when node2 judge the `if(...)` in `setHeadAndPropagate()` method line 990.

the `h==null` maybe occur. so `doReleaseShared()`

Summary:
as your requestion ,the first h means the old head ,it could be `null`(Special scenario, thread scheduling caused by time slicing),but the subsequently `(h=head==null)` must not be `null`,beacause it's the current Thread2,means the currently alive.you can think of it as a routine examination,don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

First time `head` is checked (`Node h = head`), next time - probably `node` (`setHead(node)`).

Comment: both checks are after `setHead(node)`

Comment: Yes, it is.But I want to know when h can will be null